# Integral of $(1-x^a)^\frac{1}{a}$

Tags: calculus, integration, wolfram-alpha

Does the integral $$\int (1-x^a)^\frac{1}{a} dx$$ 
have a closed form solution? The parameter $a$ is a constant and both $a$ and $x$ are positive real numbers less than or equal to $1$.

I tried plugging it in to Wolfram and got a [result](https://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281-x%5Ea%29%5E%281%2Fa%29+dx+) I don't understand. What e.g. does "$x_2 F_1(\ldots)$" mean? Or "$B_{x^a}(\ldots)$"?

Comment: Through the substitution $x^a=z$ the integral $\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^a)^{1/a}\,dx$ is a value for Euler Beta function, namely $\Gamma(1+1/a)^2 / \Gamma(1+2/a)$.$\;$ $\phantom{}_p F_q$ is the standard notation for hypergeometric functions.

Comment: The $B_z(a,b)$ is called the incomplete beta function

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: Thanks. But what is solution to the indefinite integral?

Comment: @Jens: an *incomplete* Beta function.

Comment: Maybe try expanding it with binomial theorem and then integrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use binomial theorem then integrate.

$$
(1-x^a)^{1/a} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/a}{k}(-1)^k x^{ak}
\\
\int(1-x^a)^{1/a} dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/a}{k}(-1)^k \frac{x^{ak+1}}{ak+1}
$$
Then do the usual manipulation to recognize this as a hypergeometric function
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty & \binom{1/a}{k}(-1)^k \frac{x^{ak+1}}{ak+1} =
x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1/a)(1/a-1)\cdots(1/a-k+1)}{k!}\;(-1)^k\frac{1}{ak+1}\;x^{ak}
\\ &=
x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1/a)(-1/a+1)\cdots(-1/a+k-1)}{k!}\frac{1}{a}
\frac{1}{(1/a+k)}\;x^{ak}
\\ &=
x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1/a)(-1/a+1)\cdots(-1/a+k-1)}{k!}\;
\frac{(1/a)(1/a+1)\cdots(1/a+k-1)}{(1/a+1)(1/a+2)\cdots(1/a+k)}\;x^{ak}
\\&=
x\;{}_2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{a};\frac{1}{a}+1;x^a\right)
\end{align}
We used Gauss's definition
$$
{}_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots (a+k-1)\;b(b+1)(b+2)\cdots(b+k-1)}{c(c+1)(c+2)\cdots(c+k-1)\; k!}\;z^k
$$

Answer (score 1):

*Just rephrazing what was already in comments.*

$$I=\int (1-x^a)^\frac{1}{a} dx=x \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{a};1+\frac{1}{a};x^a\right)$$

Now, as suggested, make
$$x^a=z \implies x=z^\frac{1}{a} \implies dx=\frac{1}{a}{z^{\frac{1}{a}-1}}\,dz$$ to get
$$I=\frac{1}{a} \int (1-z)^{\frac{1}{a}} z^{\frac{1}{a}-1}\,dz=\frac{1}{a}\,B_z\left(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{a}+1\right)$$